# Python - Ignorar valores NaN em um .csv e somar o resto

Tags: python, json, csv

Olá,

Tenho um arquivo .csv que estou tentando passar pra json

```
Produtos      Quantidade
    Bala          50
    Refri         NaN
    Salgado       25
```

E estou importando pra um json, queria saber como ignorar os valores NaN e retornar a soma.

Este é o codigo:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"quantida.csv", sep=";") 

totalQuantidade = sum(data['Quantidade'])

dataJSON = {
        "Volume": totalQuantidade
    }
#Escrever no JSON
with open('estoque.json', 'w') as jsonFile:
       jsonFile.write(json.dumps(dataJSON, indent=4))
print('Concluído')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando o método [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), podes especificar o valor do parametro `skipna` para excluir `NaN`s:

```
totalQuantidade = df['Quantidade'].sum(skipna=True)
```